# Google Form Response Link Not Getting Populated on Connected Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form and google sheet connected. The code also seems right, but getting error while running the script -

> "Cannot find method getResponses(string)"

Here is the code I have in place for the script.

```
var formURL = '1Ve6ihda_zQycSxaFbe2YkbegrxGbcTnNqacd_W7HQbh';
var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
var columnName = 'Edit Url' ;
var startRow = 3;

function getEditResponseUrls(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var form = FormApp.openById(formURL);
  for(var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex] == '') {
      var timestamp = data[i][0];
      var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
      if(formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
      var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

The line that is throwing error:

```
var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

The error message indicates that the value of `timestamp` is the string type.

#### Solution:

For the method of `getResponses(timestamp)`, please use the date object. So how about modifying as follows?

From:

```
var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
```

To:

```
var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(new Date(timestamp));
```

#### Note:

- I think that the value of date retrieved by `getValues()` is the date object. So it might be required to know the value of `var timestamp = data[i][0]`.

#### Reference:

- [getResponses(timestamp)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getresponsestimestamp)

If this was not the solution of your issue, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about the value of `timestamp` and/or a sample Spreadsheet?